# What is the reason for Gradle Build Scan is delayed?

Tags: gradle

I ran a Gradle build scan using `--scan`. I followed the link, entered my email then clicked the link in the email sent to me and viewed my results.

I then ran it with a much bigger project (~2000 classes and all sorts of Spring dependencies) and got an email saying this:

- "Your Build Scan is delayed"
- "Due to the high volume of Build Scans being generated currently, you can activate your Build Scan now, but there may be a delay in your ability to view it."
- "What to do?"
- "Activate your Build Scan now by following this link. Once activated and viewable, you will be able to share it with others."

If I click the link it says the scan is already activated - which makes sense since this is the activation email.

However, I never get another email saying it is ready.
I clicked on the link 24 hours later and got the same email.

Is this actually due to the success of my project and nothing to do with the servers?
How can I see the size of the scan that was sent to the servers?

Comment: Seems more like a question for Gradle's support?

Comment: Maybe. It also seems like something other people would have come across and would know the answer to.